# Install debian stretch with php5.6

Tags: php, dockerfile, debian-stretch

We are using laravel based on php version 5.6, few days ago Debian removed jessie version (8) so we need to upgrade that to 9, but the issue is its hard to use Debian 9 without php5.6 as scripts like 
docker-php-ext-install
does not seem to work there. i attach my section of the installation in the docker-file. Would appreciate if there is a solution to this

I have tried to install the pdo_mysql without the docker-php-ext-install
but it fails cannot locate that..

```
FROM debian:9.0
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install \
    apt-transport-https apt-utils \
    lsb-release \
    ca-certificates \
    wget \
    mcrypt \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    git-core \
    unzip \
&& wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
&& echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install gnupg2 php5.6-cli php5.6-fpm \
&& apt-get update \
&& docker-php-ext-install \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    mcrypt bcmath\
&& update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php5.6 90 \
&& update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

And this is the end of the build call :

```
Reading package lists...
/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-install: not found
```

Comment: Laravel supports PHP 5.6? How old is yoru Laravel version?

Comment: The docker-php-... commands are only available on php images, this is a pure debian image the docker image derives from

Comment: laravel version is 5.1.0, as for pure debian image i know, if there is a way to install the php5.6 in debian9 from other image it would be great. i just took an example that i read about here and some other links. but from all of them i get the same issue about the docker-php-ext..

Comment: php 5.6 is out of support, consider a newer version

Comment: Thats not an option for now, we have like 5 projects using the php 5.6 and alot of the functions deprecated if we move to php7. this is why i need a way to install debian 9 with php5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-php-ext-install` is a command provided by official php images. You will find it only on those images or images based on those.

Official docker php images providing php 5.6 still exist on the docker hub:

```
wget -qO- https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/php/tags | jq '.[].name' | grep -P '^"5\.6(?!\.)'
```

> ```
> "5.6"
> "5.6-alpine"
> "5.6-alpine3.4"
> "5.6-alpine3.7"
> "5.6-alpine3.8"
> "5.6-apache"
> "5.6-apache-jessie"
> "5.6-apache-stretch"
> "5.6-cli"
> "5.6-cli-alpine"
> "5.6-cli-alpine3.4"
> "5.6-cli-alpine3.7"
> "5.6-cli-alpine3.8"
> "5.6-cli-jessie"
> "5.6-cli-stretch"
> "5.6-fpm"
> "5.6-fpm-alpine"
> "5.6-fpm-alpine3.4"
> "5.6-fpm-alpine3.7"
> "5.6-fpm-alpine3.8"
> "5.6-fpm-jessie"
> "5.6-fpm-stretch"
> "5.6-jessie"
> "5.6-stretch"
> "5.6-zts"
> "5.6-zts-alpine"
> "5.6-zts-alpine3.4"
> "5.6-zts-alpine3.7"
> "5.6-zts-alpine3.8"
> "5.6-zts-jessie"
> "5.6-zts-stretch"
> ```

Furthermore, those images are built on top of debian 9:

```
docker run --rm php:5.6 cat /etc/os-release
```

> ```
> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
> NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="9"
> VERSION="9 (stretch)"
> ID=debian
> HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
> ```

and provide the `docker-php-ext-install` command:

```
docker run --rm php:5.6 which docker-php-ext-install
```

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install
> ```

---

I suggest you use one of those official image as the base for your Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        mbstring \
        mcrypt \
        pdo_mysql
```